# How do I automatically add something to a ToolStripMenu, then read the text of that item?

Tags: c#, .net, toolstripmenu

Say, for example, I have a ToolStripMenu. I have a tab already made (let's call it Download), and want a substrip of it ([the "type here" part](http://puu.sh/18EPS)) to be automaticaly made. I want it to be text that the string `downloadedString` is. Then, later, when it's clicked, I want it to fire:

```
Process.Start("google.com/" + Text of the substrip clicked);
```

How do I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do so via the Click event handler on the `ToolStripMenuItem`.

**Part 1 - programmatically adding menu items**

Just add a new `ToolStripMenuItem` to the `MenuStrip` like so:

```
ToolStripMenuItem mi = new ToolStripMenuItem("whatever");
mi.Click += new EventHandler(menuItemHandler_Click);

menuStrip1.Items.Add(mi);
```

They can all reference the same event handler (see below).

**Part 2 - event handler to start your process**

The event handler will start the process, using the text of the menu item that was clicked:

```
private void menuItemHandler_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Process.Start("google.com/" + (sender as ToolStripMenuItem).Text);
}
```

Based on the code above, `Process.Start()` will receive `google.com/whatever` as the parameter.

Comment: That doesn't add it as a part of Downloads. It does, however, add a blank space, like [this](http://puu.sh/18FPO). Any ideas why?

Comment: Because the example code adds the ToolStripMenuItem to the "root" of the MenuStrip.  If you want to add it to your existing Downloads menu, then add the new ToolStripMenuItem to the DropDownItems collection of your Downloads menu.

Comment: Ok, I got it to show up as a child of Downloads. It errors out (like last time) with the error "The system cannot find the file specified"

Comment: That only happens when I click by the way. My code is [here](http://pastebin.com/MTZDgL4a)

Comment: That's probably because when you call **Process.Start** it is looking for a file named "google.com".  I suspect that you want to actually start "http://google.com".

Comment: Yeah, I've done it before... Edit: *facepalm* Just realized. I need the Http://.